# Python, Django com vários bancos de dados

Tags: python, django, model

Para trabalhar com vários bancos de dados no framework Laravel, uma vez configurada todas as conexões nos arquivos de configuração, basta definir na model qual conexão com o banco aquela model ira usar, e então independente da operação a model sempre ira apontar para um determinado banco.

Um exemplo é quando eu tenho dois clientes cada um com seu próprio banco, e preciso realizar o CRUD nos dois bancos, com o Laravel basta eu definir qual model de qual cliente usar e as operações são realizadas normalmente.

Como faço isso usando o Django?

Answer (score 3):

Você vai conseguir fazer isso através do [Automatic Database Routing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing). É uma configuração um pouco extensa, mas vamos usar um exemplo simples e prático (retirado da documentação).

Esse vai ter alguns databases: um pra app `auth` e todas as outras apps vão usar uma configuração de primary/replica com duas replicas apenas pra leitura. Essa seria a configuração para os databases:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'auth_db': {
        'NAME': 'auth_db',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'swordfish',
    },
    'primary': {
        'NAME': 'primary',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'spam',
    },
    'replica1': {
        'NAME': 'replica1',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'eggs',
    },
    'replica2': {
        'NAME': 'replica2',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'bacon',
    },
}
```

Agora nós vamos precisar ter que lidar com o roteamento. Primeiro vamos criar um router que vai saber como enviar queries da app `auth` para o `auth_db`:

```
class AuthRouter:
    """
    Um router para controlar todas as operações de banco de
    dados dos models da app auth.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Definição do nome do banco para leitura.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
            return 'auth_db'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Definição do nome do banco para escrita.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
            return 'auth_db'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Permite relações se um model na app auth está envolvido.
        """
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'auth' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'auth':
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Certifica que a app auth aparece apenas no banco 'auth_db'.
        database.
        """
        if app_label == 'auth':
            return db == 'auth_db'
        return None
```

E aqui vamos criar um router que vai enviar tudo das outras apps para nossa configuração de primary/replica, escolhendo randomicamente de qual replica ele vai ler:

```
import random

class PrimaryReplicaRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Leitura vai para um dos dois, aleatoriamente.
        """
        return random.choice(['replica1', 'replica2'])

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Escrita sempre no primary
        """
        return 'primary'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Relações entre objetos são permitidas se ambos objetos
        estão no primary/replica.
        """
        db_list = ('primary', 'replica1', 'replica2')
        if obj1._state.db in db_list and obj2._state.db in db_list:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        return True
```

Ao final disso tudo, você vai adicionar o `DATABASE_ROUTERS` ao seu arquivo `settings.py` do projeto, com o path para as duas classes criadas anteriormente.

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.AuthRouter', 'path.to.PrimaryReplicaRouter']
```

Tem [esse outro post](https://strongarm.io/blog/multiple-databases-in-django/) que também aborda o mesmo assunto.

Comment: Eu notei que é possível ter apenas um arquivo de router, e em cada método colocar uma condicional apontando cada app para um banco especifico. É uma boa pratica?

Comment: É possível sim, mas por questões de organização e manuntenibilidade, é melhor você ir separando e ter um arquivo pra cada router, ou no mínimo um arquivo mas cada router sendo uma classe.